# Error: No CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER could be found for Visual Studio 2019 Fortran support

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, fortran, mingw

I am using CMAKE to build Open Source Projects (like those are available at GitHub etc.) and I also have installed `Visual Studio 2019`. There is a problem that CMAKE can not find Fortran compiler in my system whereas I've installed `MinGW` with Fortran compiler. The error is:

```
**The Fortran compiler identification is unknown** 
**No CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER could be found.**
```

How can I solve this problem and make CMAKE be aware of Fortran compiler?

**Note:** I tried other projects that does not require Fortran compiler and those are built successfully.

Installed software:

CMAKE 3.18.5,
Visual Studio 2019,
MinGW

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to show where your fortran executable file to `CMakeList.txt` like

```
set(CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER "C:/MinGW/bin/gfortran.exe")
```

**EDIT 2 for Visual studio 2019:**

If you want to produce `Visual Studio 2019` solution

1. Download Intel® oneAPI HPC Toolkit [here](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/tools/oneapi/hpc-toolkit/download.html).
2. If cmake cannot find Fortran compiler add a cmake flag `CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER` with the value of `ifort.exe` path that u installed above. Like `%install_path%/Intel/oneAPI/compiler/2021.1.1/windows/bin/intel64/ifort.exe`
3. Configure and generate solution.

**EDIT:**

Alright, now I understand why you get this error.  The Visual Studio generator does not support MinGW gfortran.  They are totally separate ecosystems.
Remove your build directory and create a fresh one.  Then use `cmake .. -G "MinGW Makefiles"` instead. I tried from CLI prompt of msys and successfully obtained  the libraries from Windows machine.

If you are using Intel processors, you should first set-up Fortran environment for `Visual Studio 2019`

Better to check compilation [guide](https://discourse.cmake.org/t/how-to-set-up-compilation-with-intel-fortran-compiler-on-windows-correctly/532)  and [some troubleshooting Fortran Integration Issues with visual studio](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/troubleshooting-fortran-integration-issues-with-visual-studio.html)

Comment: I did it, but I received [this](https://ibb.co/LYz2rVw) error.

Comment: What is the value for `CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM` or if it is not a private repo, could you share the git link to reproduce the error?

Comment: Yes. this [repo](https://portal.nersc.gov/project/sparse/superlu/superlu_5.2.2.tar.gz)

Comment: Checkout my edits and links. If they work for you, don't forget to mark as an answer upvote :) cheers

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try this solution and mark your answer if it works ;). best regards

Comment: I installed intel parallel studio XE and fortran problem solved, but i got another problem with this message :" Did not find or specify BLAS so configure to build internal CBLAS ". and also i ignored this and generated visual studio solution but when i tried to build solution, build failed.

Comment: Most probably you are also trying to build tests too. I generally ignore them. Just remove tests(c_test, z_test etc.) from solution and rebuild solution. This step will create related libs. Don't forget to change `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`, if you want a tidy package.

Comment: excuse me, I am not familiar with these stuffs much I just want to add a library to my C++ project but I am mixed up and I can not do this. would you please help me to add these library to my project ? having more communication via for example email or ...?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227521/discussion-between-ceopee-and-daveed).